# gob attempting to decode nil value results in EOF error

Tags: pointers, go, null, gob

I need to use the `gob` to encode some data, however, I find that "type nil" can not be processed correctly (go 1.6.2)

https://play.golang.org/p/faypK8uobF

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "log"
)

type T struct {
    A int
}

func init() {
    gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
    gob.Register(new(T))
}
func main() {
    bys := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    gob.NewEncoder(bys).Encode(map[string]interface{}{
        "v": (*T)(nil),
    })
    out := map[string]interface{}{}
    if err := gob.NewDecoder(bys).Decode(&out); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return
}
```

Output:

```
panic: EOF
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are swallowing an `error` returned by [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Encoder.Encode):

```
err := gob.NewEncoder(bys).Encode(map[string]interface{}{
    "v": (*T)(nil),
})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Output:

```
gob: gob: cannot encode nil pointer of type *main.T inside interface
```

This is generated by unexported method `Encoder.encodeInterface()`. Quoting from [`encode.go`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/encode.go), unexported method `Encoder.encodeInterface()`:

```
// Gobs can encode nil interface values but not typed interface
// values holding nil pointers, since nil pointers point to no value.
elem := iv.Elem()
if elem.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && elem.IsNil() {
    errorf("gob: cannot encode nil pointer of type %s inside interface", iv.Elem().Type())
}
```

So your `Encoder.Encode()` fails, it writes nothing to its output (which is the `bys` buffer), so attempting to read (decode) anything from it results in EOF.

But why can't you encode an `interface{}` value holding a `nil` pointer? Quoting from the package doc of [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/):

> Pointers are not transmitted, but the things they point to are transmitted; that is, the values are flattened.

Your `interface{}` contains a value of pointer type, but that pointer is `nil`, it points to nothing, it cannot be flattened.

---

Here is a related issue on github: [encoding/gob: panic on encoding nil pointer #3704](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3704)

Russ:

> gob doesn't know what a pointer is: everything gets flattened. Putting a nil pointer in an interface{} value creates a non-zero value (it's not the nil interface) that gob cannot send (it can't express 'nil pointer').

Rob Pike:

> Correct. An interface value can be transmitted only if the concrete value itself is transmittable. At least for now, that's equivalent to saying that interfaces holding typed nil pointers cannot be sent.